# @ok listener is not triggered on b-modal with jest-test-utils (vue-bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using the vue-bootstrap b-modal with the `@ok="save"` hook

The mycomponent.vue looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button @click="add">open modal</b-button>
    <b-modal static lazy id="modal-detail" @ok="save">
      <b-form-input v-model="fooName"></b-form-input>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";

import { RestClient } from "./RestClient";

@Component({ name: "fooController" })
export default class FooController extends Vue {
  public fooName = "";
  public add(): void {
    this.$root.$emit("bv::show::modal", "modal-detail");
  }
  public save(): void {
    console.log("in save method");
    RestClient.create(this.fooName);
  }
}
</script>
```

The RestClient.ts looks like this:

```js
export class RestClient {
  static create(payload: string) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

The test looks like this:

```js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import MyComponent from "./mycomponent.vue";
import { RestClient } from "./RestClient";

jest.mock("./RestClient.ts", () => ({
  RestClient: {
    create: jest.fn(() => {
      return {};
      //   return Promise.resolve({});
    })
  }
}));

describe("component test", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

  it("should call the create method on the REST client when ok-ing the modal", (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
      attachToDocument: true,
      localVue
    });
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBe(true);

    // there is just one button: the open modal button
    wrapper.find("button").trigger("click");
    const modal = wrapper.find("#modal-detail");

    modal.vm.$emit("ok");

    return wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(() => {
      expect(RestClient.create).toBeCalled();
      return wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(done);
    });
 });
});
```

I am emitting the `ok` event on the modal directly.
Then I am watching for the console.log statement in the save-method to be executed, which i cannot see in the terminal, when executing the test.

Thus, the `RestClient.create`-method is not being called. 
Why?

Answer (score 2):

`@ok` is a custom Vue event, not a native browser DOM event. The `.prevent` modifier will not work on custom Vue events.

Comment: removing the `.prevent` still does not trigger the `save`-method

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/modal/modal.js#L595 , I think the `@ok` event is in this case specific to vue-bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah it is a custom Vue component event for BootstrapVue (I wrote the code)

Comment: So how can I test wether a modal.vm.$emit("ok") actually called the associated method?

Comment: If using JEST, then set up a mock save function using `jest.fn()`, and you can still use Vue test utils to find the OK button and click it.  Note modal uses transitions, so you will need to `await` for a `requestAnimationFrame` to complete after the modal is mounted before searching for the button and clicking it. You can see how we test modals at https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/modal/modal.spec.js